# How do I make my Discord bot change status auto

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, discord, discord.js

How do I make my Discord bot change status every second

This code does not work

TypeError: client.user.setActivity is not a function

```
const activities_list = [
"with the &help command.", 
"with the developers console",
"with some code", 
"with JavaScript"
]; // creates an arraylist containing phrases you want your bot to switch through.

client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
    }, 10000); // Runs this every 10 seconds.
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: TypeError: client.user.setActivity is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your code and it totally worked as expected, a little thing: The `setInterval` function waits before executing, means in your case: it waits 10 seconds and only after that it sets the status the first time, so you might want to change your code a little bit so that it already sets a status when starting and not after the first interval is over:

```js
const actvs = [
    "with the &help command.",
    "with the developers console",
    "with some code",
    "with JavaScript"
];

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity(actvs[Math.floor(Math.random() * (actvs.length - 1) + 1)]);
    setInterval(() => {
        client.user.setActivity(actvs[Math.floor(Math.random() * (actvs.length - 1) + 1)]);
    }, 10000);
});
```

Edit: My Discord.js version is v11.5.1, it is different in v12. [Here is a link to the docs for v12](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity)

Comment: Hi Zer0 thank you , this code did not work TypeError: client.user.setActivity is not a function

Comment: @loser which version of Discord.js are you using? (You can check that in your package.json). I used v11.5.1, it may differ in the newly released v12, I haven't updated my bot so far but for this, the docs might help you. [Here you find setActivity in v12](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity)

Comment: Zer0 thank you, my version is "discord.js": "^11.1.0",

Comment: @loser then you might want to check out [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.1.0/class/ClientUser) page, you can find all methods of `client.user` at the right. There is no `setActivity` in v11.1.0, but other things like `setGame` and `setStatus`. Sadly I can't help you much with that but you can read on how those work

Comment: Remember: This may get you ratelimited and / or your bot (From what I heard) may be banned. I recommend only looping after 30 secs or so